# check if Kubernetes deployment was sucessful in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, kubernetes, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with Kubernetes version 1.14.7.

I have build CI/CD pipelines to deploy newly created images to the cluster.

I am using kubectl apply to update a specific deployment with the new image. sometimes and for many reasons, the deployment fails, for example ImagePullBackOff.

is there a command to run after the kubectl apply command to check if the pod creation and deployment was successful?

Comment: Check the events section after running the command: kubectl -n [your namespace] describe pod [your pod name] and check what was the reason of the ImagePullBackOff and in my opinion try first to fix the issue you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to wait for deployment to become available with a configured timeout like

`kubectl wait --for=condition=available --timeout=60s deploy/myapp`

otherwise `kubectl rollout status` can be used but it may stuck forever in some rare cases and will require manual cancellation of pipeline if that happens.

Comment: I dont know If I am overseeing anything. But for me `--timeout` works with kubectl rollout status as well.

Answer (score 6):

For this purpose Kubernetes has  `kubectl rollout` and you should use option `status`.

> By default 'rollout status' will watch the status of the latest rollout until it's done. If you don't want to wait for the rollout to finish then you can use --watch=false. Note that if a new rollout starts in-between, then 'rollout status' will continue watching the latest revision. If you want to pin to a specific revision and abort if it is rolled over by another revision, use --revision=N where N is the revision you need to watch for.

You can read the full description [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rollout)

If you use `kubect apply -f myapp.yaml` and check `rollout status` you will see:

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment myapp
Waiting for deployment "myapp" rollout to finish: 0 of 3 updated replicas are available…
Waiting for deployment "myapp" rollout to finish: 1 of 3 updated replicas are available…
Waiting for deployment "myapp" rollout to finish: 2 of 3 updated replicas are available…
deployment "myapp" successfully rolled out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output through jq:

```
kubectl get pod -o=json | jq '.items[]|select(any( .status.containerStatuses[]; .state.waiting.reason=="ImagePullBackOff"))|.metadata.name'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [kubediff](https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff) tool is a perfect match for your task:

> Kubediff is a tool for Kubernetes to show you the differences between your running configuration and your version controlled configuration.

The tool can be used from the command line and as a Pod in the cluster that continuously compares YAML files in the configured repository with the current state of the cluster.

```
$ ./kubediff
Usage: kubediff [options] <dir/file>...

Compare yaml files in <dir> to running state in kubernetes and print the
differences.  This is useful to ensure you have applied all your changes to the
appropriate environment.  This tools runs kubectl, so unless your
~/.kube/config is configured for the correct environment, you will need to
supply the kubeconfig for the appropriate environment.
```

`kubediff` returns the status to `stdout` and non-zero exit code when difference is found. You can change this behavior using command line arguments.

You may also want to check the good article about validating YAML files:

- [Validating Kubernetes Deployment YAMLs](https://medium.com/schkn/validating-kubernetes-deployment-yamls-d46a16a7e664)